# i want to do a square in python but im doing something wrong

Tags: python

I wrote this code : you enter the square width and it creates one, but when the square is created `None` appears too. Why?

```
def square(width):
    if width>=4 and width% 2 ==0:
     inferior_superior(width)
     for i in range(2):
         side(width)
     inferior_superior(width)
def inferior_superior(width):
     print("+" + "-"*(width-2) + "+")
def side(width):
    print('|' + ' '*(width-2) + '|')
```

Comment: none of these function return anything. So what exactly is `None`? also how are you calling this function?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. You calling it like `square(4)`. Right?

Comment: Probably, you are doing `print(square(8))` in that case the `sqaure()` method returns `None` which gets printed as output

Comment: call the square function with a value >=4 and divideable by 2 (see line 2), like square(16)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that, at the python prompt, `square` works fine:

```
>>> square(6)
+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+
```

If, however, you print the result of `square`, you will see none:

```
>>> print(square(6))
+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+
None
```

The solution is to use `square(n)` by itself, not `print(square(n))`.

#### Alternative

You can assign a return value to `square` if you like:

```
>>> def square(width):
...     if width>=4 and width% 2 ==0:
...      inferior_superior(width)
...      for i in range(2):
...          side(width)
...      inferior_superior(width)
...      return "Everything works A-OK."
...
```

Now, observe:

```
>>> print(square(6))
+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+
Everything works A-OK.
```

Comment: `print(square(6))` prints `None` because `square()` function returns nothing which is treated as `None`. And you end up printing the `None` value